# HAProxy dynamic configuration

Tags: haproxy

Here is my setup:

- we do have one external load balancer (AWS) attached to root domain mydomain.com
- external load balancer forward traffic to HAProxy instance, and haproxy have to forward it further to on of two internal load balancers
- we have 2 internal load balancers, first point to latest version of our app, second to minus one version
- each of our client can have 1 to many subdomains like sub1.mydomain.com, sub2. sub3
- some subdomains should be redirected to old version, some to new, so same client can have old and new in subdomains

Basically:

```
 sub1.mydomain.com -> latest-load-balancer
 sub2.mydomain.com -> older-load-balancer
```

The problem is how to setup this routing, we can't stop/start haproxy for each new subdomain. And it could be more them 10k of that subdomains in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. haproxy can use [maps](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#7.3.1-map) to decide which backend (internal load balancer) to use, based on the domain.
2. haproxy can be [*reloaded*](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/management.html#4) instead of *restarted* when the map changes.
3. If you do not wish to even reload, you could pass [`map`](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/management.html#9.2-add%20map) commands to the unix socket, thus changing the map in realtime.

Comment: Ross, you gave me really interesting direction, thanks. Saying true I've already found workaround with nginx+redis+lua, but your way seems to be more natural, I'll give a try.

Comment: Can you explain more on third step, in particular I don't sure I understand what you mean by "you could pass map commands to the unix socket" thanks.

Comment: See the link in my 3rd point (the word `map` is the link). If you telnet to the stats socket then you can use the `add map` command to add entries to the map. I'm sure there's another command for deleting entries.